# Low Level Design, Implementing pool of checks and choosing checks from this pool to create a strategy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

**Problem Context**

Suppose within a bank's risk department, we have a strategy (call it 'A') to calculate the risk a customer. This calculation is done by amalgamation of a number of checks i.e if the customer is married/unmarried, Salaried/Non-salaried etc.

These can be simple and complex checks which overall give us the risk of the customer, so each of these checks are implemented as a class where each class(check) gives its decision.

We also develop another Strategy (call it 'B') to run parallel for A/B testing. i.e let's say 20% of customers go through this strategy rather than 'A' for risk calculation. This strategy has a lot of similar checks but a couple of new checks as well.

so the overall scenario would look something like below.

[image]

The list of checks for each strategy will be fetched from database, so that we can have multiple strategies as well as have a store of all the strategies for risk-calculation.We can generate Strategy A or Strategy B at runtime by injecting checks.
Checks making up strategy A and B can be completely different, somewhat different or very little different
[image]

**Problem**
I am not able to get to a low-level design or how can I implement it. Class structure, or how to inject these checks dynamically into a strategy class after reading the list of checks for the database.

any help or hints or links would be very much appreciated

While a Strategy pattern could be suggested here, but I don't think it will work if Strategy A and Strategy B have no checks in common

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [GoF Strategy patern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

> For instance, a class that performs validation on incoming data may use the strategy pattern to select a validation algorithm depending on the type of data, the source of the data, user choice, or other discriminating factors. These factors are not known until run-time and may require radically different validation to be performed. The validation algorithms (strategies), encapsulated separately from the validating object, may be used by other validating objects in different areas of the system (or even different systems) without code duplication.

Comment: The strategy pattern won't work here. It won't work in case where there is no common functionality between these two strategies A,B so that we can abstract them out and use the strategy pattern.